# Is there a `pip` flag to upgrage to latest release candidate

Tags: python, pip

First I want to confirm if this is expected pip behaviour or not:

We're using `Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager` as an onsite package repository, and `setuptools_scm` to version our packages. So when I build a release candidate it obtains a version such as `0.4.1rc1`

I publish this to the repository `twine upload -r pypi dist/mypkg-0.4.1rc1-py3-none-any.whl`

If I switch to another project that has `mypkg` and try to update (say 0.4.0 is currently installed)

```
$pip install -U mypkg --index-url https://build.xyz.com/repository/pypi-all/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: mypkg in ./.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.4.0)
```

So it won't upgrade `0.4.0` to `0.4.1-rc1` - I'd imagine this is how pip is supposed to work, you need to explicitly specify that you want to upgrade to a non-release version but would like confirmation.

Assuming this is correct behaviour, is there a flag to override so I can automatically upgrade to the latest release candidate? And is there then an option to further control what gets installed (i.e. latest release candidate or latest dev build for example). I'm aware of PEP 440 versioning (which is what `setuptools_scm` follows)

Comment: Sorry I though I had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`--pre`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-pre) flag:

```
pip install --pre -U mypkg
```

By default `pip` will only look for stable versions, but `--pre` will allow `pip` to install any pre-release versions too.